# screenshot failed in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium

I am trying to capture the screenshot while running selenium script. But am getting below error. anyone help me on this to resolve it.

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 123     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.internal.Base64Encoder.mapCharToInt(Base64Encoder.java:89)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.internal.Base64Encoder.decode(Base64Encoder.java:76)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.OutputType$2.convertFromBase64Png(OutputType.java:57)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.OutputType$2.convertFromBase64Png(OutputType.java:1)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.OutputType$3.convertFromBase64Png(OutputType.java:75)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.OutputType$3.convertFromBase64Png(OutputType.java:1)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.getScreenshotAs(RemoteWebDriver.java:339)

am using below code,

```
File scrFile = ( (TakesScreenshot) driver ).getScreenshotAs( OutputType.FILE );     
            nextVal = seq.incrementAndGet();
            FileUtils.copyFile( scrFile, new File( "./Screenshots/Sanity/" + nextVal + ".png" ) );
```

Comment: What is the exact version of your webdriver jar?

Comment: selenium-2.53.1.jar

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code. It is probably caused by the driver implementation. If this is not just a temporary run-time issue, you should try another selenium version.

Comment: Issue got fixed after updated my selenium webdriver jar and Chromedriver to latest version. Now we are able to capture screenshot without any issues.

Comment: You should write your solution as answer to your own question so that others can learn from it.

Answer (score 0):

Issue got fixed after updated my selenium webdriver jar and Chromedriver[2.23] to latest version. Now we are able to capture screenshot without any issues while running.